# Registering Svelte components outside the main project to be used in the main project

Tags: javascript, plugins, svelte

I’m writing a plugin that renders a page and must be able to render sections that will come from a different plugin (bundle).

The project is setup with npm, webpack, and svelte-loader.

The base idea is that I need to render something inside my Svelte page that must come from a different plugin/project, but I'm not able to do this and run into some errors.

I made a global registry where I can register the Svelte components from the other plugin, something like this:

```
// Made available in main plugin (app.js)
window.appSections = [];

// This adds the section to the registry in another plugin (pluginb.js)
import {CustomSection} from "./CustomSection.svelte";
appSections.push( CustomSection )
```

In my main app, I loop through the sections and want to render them inside my Svelte template like this:

```
// Main .svelte template

{#each externalSections as section}
    <svelte:component this={section} bind:data={data}></svelte:component>
{/each}
```

All works well when I register a simple section in the file where my main Svelte app is registered and renderd to the DOM which makes sense.

But when I register a section from another plugin/file (see first code block), it gives an error during the loop.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$$')
at init (Component.js:120:1)
```

My questions:

1. Is it possible to register and use Svelte components outside the main project file and use them in the main project?
2. Why does this error occur for sections registered outside the main plugin file?
3. Is there a better way of doing something similar?

Comment: For one thing, the import you specified looks wrong, it uses a named import when component imports use the default import. (Unless that not the actual code you run).

Comment: Sorry, I scaffolded the needed code from my project for sharing here. Import logic etc is correct. When I use the exact code from my main plugin file and port it to a different plugin, it does not work.

But I found the following post where a big part of the issue is explained:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65484019/how-can-i-manually-compile-a-svelte-component-down-to-the-final-javascript-and-c

Expecially the part: Mind the trap: Svelte can't be duplicated

Comment: That would have been my suspicion. Is there anything here that make this issue significantly different from the linked question? If not, this should be closed or removed.